# Append 2 column variables in unix

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have a file as follows.
file1.csv

```
H,2 A:B,pq
D,34 C:B,wq
D,64 F:B,rq
D,6 R:B,tq
```

I want to format 2nd a column as follows

```
H,02 0A:0B,pq
D,34 0C:0B,wq
D,64 0F:0B,rq
D,06 0R:0B,tq
```

I am able to separate the column and format it but cannot merge it
I use following command

```
formated_nums =`awk -F"," '{print $2}' file1.csv | awk '{print $1}' | awk '{if(length($1)!=2){$1="0"$1}}1'`
formated_letters = `awk -F"," '{print $2}' file1.csv | awk '{print $2}' | awk -F":" '{if(length($1)!=2){$1="0"$1}; if(length($2)!=2){$2="0"$2}}1'| awk '{print $1":"$2}'`
```

Now I want to merge formated_nums and formated_letters with a space in between

I tried `echo "${formated_nums} ${formated_letters}"` but it takes variables as rows and appends the whole thing as a row

Comment: use `printf` instead of `print` that add a new line at the end. See other reply to avoid piped awk. Awk is powerfull an can easily handle such double trnasformation, it is made for.

Comment: In a comment under a now deleted answer you said "it won't work for an input like `H,2 0A:B,pq`". Obviously all we have to go on is what you tell us so if you need to handle input like that (or anything else) then [edit] your question to include that in your sample input/output. And please do it soon before anyone else wastes time offering you solutions based on sample input that doesn't reflect your real input and so cannot work.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest I found in awk is to use another separation including space and ':' and reformat the final layout. The only real tricky part is the number that need sometimes to add a 0 in front but it's trivial in formating because number are never bigger than 2 digit (here)

```
awk -F '[[:blank:],:]' '{printf("%s,%02d 0%s:0%s,%s", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5)}' YourFile
```

Assuming your data are in the same format (no bigger latest field with space or other "separator" inside)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative awk solution based on gnu awk :

```
awk -F"[, :]" '{sub($2,sprintf("%02d",$2));sub($3,"0" $3);sub($4,"0" $4)}1' file1

H,02 0A:0B,pq
D,34 0C:0B,wq
D,64 0F:0B,rq
D,06 0R:0B,tq
```

Comment: There's nothing gawk-specific about that, it'll behave the same in any awk. It just won't work if the input contains regexp or backreference metacharacters.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is what you're really looking for:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS=","; p=2 }
    { split($2,t,/[ :]/); for (i in t) {n=length(t[i]); t[i] = (n<p ? sprintf("%0*s",p-n,0) : "") t[i]; $2=t[1]" "t[2]":"t[3]} }
    1
' file
H,02 0A:0B,pq
D,34 0C:0B,wq
D,64 0F:0B,rq
D,06 0R:0B,tq
```